# Where is height for inline item from

Tags: css

[image]
[image]

JSFiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/cs2tegy1/

As you can see, the content of inline item (`<span>`) are inside green box.My question is where is height of the box from .
Firstly it is not the `height` property which is not applicable to `inline` at all.
Secondly ,it is not `line-height` as well ,the only thing it affect is that space between the boxes.

So, where is the height from?

Comment: Provide the complete example (html/css). You can use snippet for that or jsfiddle for example.

Comment: @Dekel The question is quite simply. Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cs2tegy1/

Comment: The `height` of inline-styled elements is based on their content (and not based on their container), if thats what you are asking.

Comment: @Dekel I think the height of green box is determined by `height` rather than `line-height`.  And for now ,it seem to me that the `height` is affect by "content"  and `padding` implicitly.Setting `height` directly just can not work.Still not sure how the `height` is calculated

Comment: @Dekel Also,I am really struggling a way to make `line-height` visible in browser

Comment: Note that for inline elements the `line-height` will not affect the background-color (but only the padding between the lines): https://jsfiddle.net/eqg3evur/

Comment: @Guigui, what browser version do you use? I have tried your snippet and `line-height` actually changes the height of the span.

Comment: @Siavas ,you mean the `line-height` change the height of "green box",this is definitely not true for chrome

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now, Guigui. Taking from @Dekel's explanation, is this the result you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/eqg3evur/1/

Comment: @Siavas ,I am just following a tutorial and come up some question myself http://book.mixu.net/css/2-box-model.html

Comment: @Siavas, I think he wants an explanation (and not a solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the conversation in comments, I understand your question is how the height of the green box/area is being calculated.

This area is not calculated by either `height` or `line-height` attributes. This area is, without any padding, the minimum area which covers all the letters in the `span` element - which is actually the font-size of your text.

Adding a border or padding to the `span`, it will make the green area bigger by that size.

Comment: The height of the line-box is equal to the value of `line-height`.

Comment: @zer00ne but not the height of the "green area"

Comment: I see just that then it's content-area which is determined by font and padding.

Answer (score 1):

`line-height:normal` is the default, which is about 1.2x`font-size` for the major browsers. Look in the <kbd>Computed Style</kbd> tab.

> On non-replaced inline elements, **line-height specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height**.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

That span is a non-replaced inline element and it's height defaulted to auto (which is irrelevant, since height doesn't apply to it unless it was anything but inline) it defers to line-height of about 1.2.

> In the case of a line which contains only inline non-replaced elements which are all the same font-size and line-height, and all of which have the same vertical alignment, the solution is simple. The content-area is defined by the font-size of the elements, and **the height of the line-box is equal to the value of line-height.**

http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/inline-format.html

[image]

Sorry, 16px x 1.2 = 19.2px

Comment: `line-height` can not increase the height of the box ,which is a surprise to me (maybe you as well)

Comment: What is this *"box"* you speak of, sir? You haven't provided any code.

Comment: By "box", I mean the green one

Comment: On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that is used to calculate line box height. That span is a non-replaced inline element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height What is the font-size?

Comment: I think the height of green box is determined by `height` rather than `line-height` and for now ,it seem to me that the `height` is affect by "content"  and `padding` implicitly.Setting `height` directly just can not work

Comment: No, it's `line-height`, see the update.

Comment: Thanks for you help ! But my question is to how the "height of green area" is calculated, rather than how the `line-height` is calculate .What is more ,"height of green area" is **not** the same as `line-height` for sure.Just set the `line-height` and you will notice that the "green box height" will not be changed at all

Comment: If the green-box is your only concern that would be content-area determined by font, and padding.

Comment: After I check your answer more closely ,I suppose this answer is wrong and thus misleading to others.You use the rule to get "green area" 19px and run the number to say `line-height` is also 19px .But I believe it is just an incidence. We can not conclude that "green area" is determined by `line-height`.Please update this answer

Comment: I suppose the `line-height` calculate to the `content height` (which is based on `font-size`) by default.But `line-height` is subject to change while `content height` is fixed because it is derived from `font-size`

Comment: If you specify **content-area** because that's what you meant, I would adjust accordingly. I see a span with a green background, not a "green-area". You say "I think the height of green box is determined by height" is that the property height or a "green height"?

Comment: All measurements are subject to change, and content area is not a constant due to the fact font-family has variations in ascenders and descenders as @Johannes stated.

Comment: "height measured by ruler" === "Iine-height calculated by 1.2 * font-size" is kind of misleading. My first reaction is that the "green height" is from `line-heigh` ,that is why they are equal

Comment: When I said "green height", I was being facetious. "green anything" is misleading if you already have specific terms to coincide what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

it's just the font-size (and height), including the space for the ascenders and descenders of letters like j, Q, p T F etc. (which can be different for every font)